# Using Java 11 HttpClient.send() working like asynchronous call and making current thread to be in WAITING state for long time. Kindly hep to resolve

Tags: java, java-11

Using java11 Http Client as below,

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder().version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1).followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.NORMAL).connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(Long.valueOf(matchMakerHttpConnectionTimeout))).build();

HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder().POST(requestBody).uri(URI.create(baseurl)).timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(requestTimeOut))
.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken).build();

```
            LOGGER.info("Base url : {} with request body : {}", baseurl, request);
            HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(httpRequest,BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

But seems after invoking httpclient.send, threads going on to WAITING state for long time and does not comes back to pool for picking other jobs which increases CPU spike as well. It should actually need to be synchronous call right? Why is it executing like asynchrounous way?

```
"pool-3-thread-2" #57 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=7204.26ms elapsed=16809.99s tid=0x000056033ed08800 nid=0x59 waiting on condition  [0x00007f263fc89000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@11.0.5/Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000c54cb950> (a java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Signaller)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@11.0.5/LockSupport.java:194)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Signaller.block(java.base@11.0.5/CompletableFuture.java:1796)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(java.base@11.0.5/ForkJoinPool.java:3128)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.waitingGet(java.base@11.0.5/CompletableFuture.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(java.base@11.0.5/CompletableFuture.java:1998)
    at jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(java.net.http@11.0.5/HttpClientImpl.java:541)
    at jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(java.net.http@11.0.5/HttpClientFacade.java:119)
    at com.comcast.bo.rlcm.cmdp.helper.SampleServiceHelper.invokeAPI(SampleServiceHelper.java:273)
    at com.comcast.bo.rlcm.cmdp.helper.SampleServiceHelper.lambda$invokeCmAPI$7(SampleServiceHelper.java:220)
    at com.comcast.bo.rlcm.cmdp.helper.SampleServiceHelper$$Lambda$1778/0x0000000100d66440.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.forEach(java.base@11.0.5/HashMap.java:1336)
    at com.comcast.bo.rlcm.cmdp.helper.SampleClassA.invokeHttpClientForExternalApi(SampleService.java:201)
    at com.comcast.bo.rlcm.cmdp.service.SampleService.lambda$processCm$4(SampleService.java:310)
    at com.comcast.bo.rlcm.cmdp.service.SampleService$$Lambda$1302/0x0000000100c6b840.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.forEach(java.base@11.0.5/ConcurrentHashMap.java:1603)
    at com.comcast.bo.rlcm.cmdp.service.SampleService.processCm(SampleService.java:224)
    at com.comcast.bo.rlcm.cmdp.service.SampleService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f43afa24.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:687)
    at com.comcast.bo.rlcm.cmdp.service.SampleService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$33bd9b1c.processCm(<generated>)
    at com.comcast.bo.rlcm.cmdp.service.SampleService2.processCM(SampleService2.java:99)
    at com.comcast.bo.rlcm.cmdp.cmjob.processor.SampleProcessor.run(SampleProcessor.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(java.base@11.0.5/Executors.java:515)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(java.base@11.0.5/FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@11.0.5/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@11.0.5/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.5/Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: You called the blocking method, what behaviour do you expect and why?

Comment: I have configured timeout But even if we did not get response from external api using send() call for long time, its not getting Timeout. Kindly help on why it is not getting timeout?

Answer (score 4):

As it is written in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html) of HttpClient class:

> Requests can be sent either synchronously or asynchronously:
>
> - send(HttpRequest, BodyHandler) blocks until the request has been sent and the response has been received.
> - sendAsync(HttpRequest, BodyHandler) sends the request and receives the response asynchronously. The sendAsync method returns immediately with a CompletableFuture...

So if you need not to wait the response and not to block the current thread - use the sendAsync method.

Comment: I have used send() method, But it make thread to WAITING state. it should be synchronous only right?  why making current thread to waiting state. i see more thread like this in waiting state.

Comment: Send() is synchronous right  . Why is it executing in thread . Is it expected? I want synchronous call actually but it seems executing asynchronous makes thread waiting.

Comment: Kindly help on this

Comment: I have few questions as below,
1)Also why am i getting this log many times in thread dump? 
2)Also We have configured timeout, But we see httpClient not getting timeout and not getting response also from external call happened via HttpClient.send(). Any idea on why timeout not happening? But we set timeout on HttpRequest and connectTimeout on HttpClient object.

Comment: Am i missing any thing here ?, HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder().version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1).followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.NORMAL).connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(Long.valueOf(matchMakerHttpConnectionTimeout))).build();

HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder().POST(requestBody).uri(URI.create(baseurl)).timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(requestTimeOut)) .setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8") .setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken).build();

Comment: @ Boris the Spider and Egor Kindly reply for the queries and help.

Comment: Still I have one question ... since using timeout shouldnt this be setting thread state to TIMED_WAITING instead of WAITING??